# Passing curl results to wget with bash

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I have a small script that  i'd like to use with cron.
Purpose: Get webpage with links, extract dates from link and download files.
Script below is not working 100% and i can't see the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(curl http://107.155.72.213/anarirecap.php 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | grep '_whole_1_3000.mp4'); do
GAMEDAY=$(echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}')
wget "$i" --output-document="$GAMEDAY.mp4"
done
```

It get's the webpage "curl http://...etc" - works

$DAY - extracts the date - works.

wget part not working when i add $DAY. I'm i blind ... what am i missing.

Comment: What does `set -x` say is happening?

Comment: On a different point, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor. Personally, I'd write this code entirely differently, using a proper HTML parser to extract links (`xmlstarlet` will do the trick if content is XHTML; `xmllint --html` can convert HTML to XHTML if it's not) rather than trying to futz around with `grep`.

Comment: Also, you've got a bunch of quoting bugs. http://shellcheck.net/ will point those out to you.

Comment: Beyond that, though, how are we supposed to test this without the *real* URL you're using, or a sample HTML file pastebinned somewhere that reproduces the bug (if you can't show the genuine code)?

Comment: Also, you don't need grep to extract the date at all; bash has built-in regex support with the `=~` operator.

Comment: ...and, as an aside, all-caps variable names are best avoided -- all-caps names are reserved by convention for environment variables and builtins; using at least one lower-case letter in other variable names prevents unintentional conflicts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i added exact code that i have.

Comment: With your exact code, I get no (zero) matching links in the HTML returned.

Comment: That is to say: The remote server is returning: `Vaihda päivää: <br> <a href="?date=20150512"rel="nofollow" rel="nofollow">12-05-2015</a> - <b> <a href="?date=20150513" rel="nofollow">13-05-2015</a> </b> - <a href="?date=20150514" rel="nofollow">14-05-2015</a><h2> <img src="capenguinsals.gif" height="50" width="90">@<img src="rangers.gif" height="50" width="90"> 02:30 | Game ID: 2014030227 </h2><li><img src="capenguinsals.gif" height="25" width="25"> <a href="Nothing found">Nothing found</a><li><img src="rangers.gif" height="25" width="25"> <a href="Nothing found">Nothing found</a></table>`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. There is no links at the moment.
Was 15 minutes ago ....

Comment: This is part of why I suggested pastebinning test data yourself (ideally to somewhere with no ads, ie. http://ix.io/, http://sprunge.us/, https://gist.github.com/, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy here's the bash -x output:
http://pastebin.ca/3002235

Comment: Actually, if you'd given the actual error message (`2015/05/12.mp4: No such file or directory`) in the question, that would have been enough to derive the answer, instead of making us wait until you pastebinned the `set -x` results.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your output format here:

```
wget "$i" -O 2015/05/12.mp4
```

This is looking for a directory named `2015` with a subdirectory named `05` in which to place the file `12.mp4`. Those directories don't exist, so you get `2015/05/12.mp4: No such file or directory`.

If you want to replace the `/`s with underscores:

```
wget -O "${GAMEDAY//\//_}" "$i"
```

Alternately, if you want to create the directories if they don't exist:

```
mkdir -p -- "(dirname "$GAMEDAY")"
wget -O "$GAMEDAY" "$i"
```

Comment: That was it. I do not have directory 2015 and it subfolders.
Thank you!